# Sumif Dates are equal or greater with exception

Tags: excel-formula

Hello I am working with a formula that adds a range of cells after comparing dates. For example range A1:A5 has random dates within the year 2017, range B1:B5 each contain the number 10, cell C3 contains the word "OFF". Range A6:A371 begins with 1/1/17 and ends with 12/31/17. I would like a formula that adds the 10 onwards beginning on the date mentioned in A1:A5 but not if it says "OFF" from that date onwards. The formula I have to add them is

=SUMIF(A7,">="&$A$1,$B$1)+SUMIF(A7,">="&$A$2,$B$2)+SUMIF(A7,">="&$A$3,$B$3)+SUMIF(A7,">="&$A$4,$B$4)+SUMIF(A7,">="&$A$5,$B$5)

Is there a better formula and how can I have it not include the date that has "OFF" in column C? I hope I have explained the problem and goal well, if not please ask me to clarify further.

Comment: This formula seems to do it =SUMIFS($B$1,A70,">="&$A$1,$C$1,"<>OFF")+SUMIFS($B$2,A70,">="&$A$2,$C$2,"<>OFF")+SUMIFS($B$3,A70,">="&$A$3,$C$3,"<>OFF")+SUMIFS($B$4,A70,">="&$A$4,$C$4,"<>OFF")+SUMIFS($B$5,A70,">="&$A$5,$C$5,"<>OFF") but just for curiosity is there a better formula because the actual data is much larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B6 put:

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$5,$A$1:$A$5,"<=" & A6,$C$1:$C$5,"<>OFF")
```

Then copy down the dataset

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was probably a better way to write the formula! This does the trick.